# optimizing test cases

Tags: java, performance, optimization, junit

I have few thousands of test cases. There are 2 types of testing being done. What is automated on multiple blades, integrated by **TeamCity**. The other is manual testing.

The same test cases, when run on **TeamCity** takes no less than 60 minutes (one class and each class has 24 test cases). The same class if run locally takes about 10 min max.

I want to see what is going on and why the Teamcity test cases are taking so long. Any pointers?

P.S:

- The environment is same on local and teamcity machines
- I have already asked this question on stack overflow and all of them recommended **YourKit**. I will try this option later.

Answer (score 1):

Try recording how long each test takes to see if particular tests are slow. Try running the tests outside teamcity on the same machine. It is likely to be nothing to do with teamcity.

Comment: already done that. The bottle necks are few classes which are taking like 60 min and when run on local machine, they took no more than 10 min. right now, I can't test them on the same machine the teamcity is installed. any other suggestion?

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't be able to run them yourself without teamcity. It is highly likely they are using a network resource, such as a network file system or database server.  I suspect they don't a good connection or are mis-configured.  Do you know what these classes do?  even 10 mins is a long test for a few classes. Why don't they take 10 seconds?

Comment: These classes are testing some DAO functionalities and the database which is being used has millions of records. so it takes some time. I am not sure about this network/filesystem thing of teamcity. I gotta double check. but one thing that i am sure is that teamcity is using its local database.